# Google places iOS SDK Not returning nearby places when searched

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places

I am using google places iOS SDK to get the nearby places when searched. I had simulated the Denver location on my device via Xcode. But when searching for "**Starbucks**", i was expecting to see "**Starbucks, 3110 E 1st Ave, Denver, CO 80206**" in the list. But i don't. I can see it only when i search with "**Starbucks, 3110 E**". Below is the code am using

```
    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter;
    GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
    acController.delegate = self;
    acController.autocompleteFilter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [self locationWithBearing:userLocation.course distance:30000.0 fromLocation:userLocation.coordinate];

    acController.autocompleteBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc]initWithCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate coordinate:newLocation];
```

newlocation is calculated with 30 miles range from userlocation.

Please correct me if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Why this question is tagged `Android` !

Comment: Hi Atef, I have same issue in Android too.. so thought of tagging that too... do i need to remove it?

Comment: You can't post one question and one code for both Android and IOS as they are different and STO readers are also different, please post another question. Any way @Selvin has edited you question and removed the Android Tag

Comment: Thanks for editing @Selvin .. will not do again...

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide bounds for nearby locations.

```
 func openPlacePicker(){      

let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController() 
    let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!,
                                                longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude.abs)! + 1,
                                                longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude.abs)! + 1)

    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
                                     coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

    acController.autocompleteBounds = bounds

    acController.delegate = self
    present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)



}
```